# VBA after a couple of iterations internet explorer hangs

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have a problem with Intenet Explorer hanging up on loading.
I wrote a code that opens up two Internet Explorer objects. One object loads house listings the macro pulls the url these listings and the other browser object (IE2) goes through these listings loading them in the browser. Here's the site: [https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot?previousSearchId=25](http://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot?previousSearchId=25).

I used this macro on my work computer (windows 7) and it works fine. However, when I try using this macro on my laptop IE2 loads about 10 listings after which when IE2 tries to load another listing url (linkki2) it just keeps on loading the webpage without anything appearing in the browser. If I close the macro and restart it at the same listing it loads fine and works for about another ten loads until failing again. I tried to avoid using ie by using MSXML2.XMLHTTP but this doesn't load all of the required code. I need the following part `<a href ="https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot/tampere/13665769"`but using

```
xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
xml_obj.send
html_doc.body.outerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
```

Doesn't get me the full code of the site.

Here's the code in question.

```
Function oikotie(i, IE2, ie, linkki, y)
k = 0

ie.navigate (linkki & y)
Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4 And ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
p = 0
'i = 784
Do While k <= 23
    'kaynnistaIE2
    If p = 9 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        p = 0
    End If
    linkki2 = ie.document.body.getelementsbyclassname("small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns left")(k).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href

    IE2.navigate (linkki2)
    Do While IE2.ReadyState <> 4 And IE2.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    t = 0

    Do While t <= 6
        If InStr(IE2.document.body.getelementsbyclassname("collapse target-properties ng-isolate-scope collapsable expanded")(2).getelementsbyclassname("row accordion_padding")(t).innertext, "Taloyhtiön nimi") <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = IE2.document.body.getelementsbyclassname("collapse target-properties ng-isolate-scope collapsable expanded")(2).getelementsbyclassname("row accordion_padding")(2).getelementsbyclassname("large-8 medium-9 columns left-align property")(0).innertext
            i = i + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        t = t + 1
    Loop
    p = p + 1
    k = k + 1
Loop

oikotie = i

End Function
```

I'd like to know how to solve the problem of IE2 loading and never finishing, or a workaround that didn't require using a browser at all.

Comment: why declaring all arguments as variant? Function oikotie(i, IE2, ie, linkki, y)

Comment: instead ie object you can use msxml 6.0